# Exception: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContex

Tags: spring, security

Recently I'm using spring security to control the access permission for methods. Accessing a page can trigger the authentication method (specified in @PreAuthorize) to decide if the user has the premission.

But I'm using Spring scheduled job (the method with @Scheduled), that means the method is running automatically without session context. If the method calls some function with @PreAuthorize, it can't pass the authentication. It doesn't give a "true" or "false" to tell whether the access is accepted or denied. It gives the following exception. It's very annoying!

==================================================================================

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:325)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:196)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy40.refreshGlobalCacheStrategyMetrics(Unknown Source)
at org.sly.main.server.service.system.scheduling.MaintenanceServiceImpl.runRecreateStrategyMetricsCache(MaintenanceServiceImpl.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:80)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

==================================================================================

I've searched many pages to try to figure it out, but I can't find the final solution for that.

A page in springsource.org shows the problem:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#auth-exception-credentials-not-found

> 1.5. I get an exception with the message "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext". What's wrong?
>
> This is a another debug level message which occurs the first time an
>   anonymous user attempts to access a protected resource, but when you
>   do not have an AnonymousAuthenticationFilter in your filter chain
>   configuration.
>
> DEBUG [ExceptionTranslationFilter] - Authentication exception
>   occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point
>   org.springframework.security.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException:
>   An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext   at
>   org.springframework.security.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:342)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:254)

And I find another page to describe how to configure AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/anonymous.html

It says the configuration for that should be :

```
<bean id="anonymousAuthFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
  <property name="key" value="foobar"/>
  <property name="userAttribute" value="anonymousUser,ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
</bean>

<bean id="anonymousAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider">
  <property name="key" value="foobar"/>
</bean>
```

So I configure it in my application-security.xml but it doesn't make any difference.

```
<beans:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/**"
            filters="anonymousAuthFilter" />
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</beans:bean>
<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////// -->
<!-- ////for AnonymousAuthenticationFilter//// -->
<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////// -->
<beans:bean id="anonymousAuthFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="key" value="foobar" />
    <beans:property name="userAttribute" value="anonymousUser,ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="anonymousAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="key" value="foobar" />
</beans:bean>
```

Is anybody proficient in spring security?

Answer (score 0):

From the exception and your configuration I see that there is no authentication process. Which is necessary for any access to secured resources. So you should be redirected to the `entryPoint` page.

Based On the filter configuration of yours, I see no other filters, which is odd. Are you using namespaces or filter-chains? If the latter is true, add other filters as well. You might have to look at [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html) to find out which filters are necessary for your task.